# Occupational Outlook Handbook dataset

Tags: usa, data.gov, economics

Where can I download BLS [Occupational Outlook Handbook](http://www.bls.gov/ooh/) data?

You can find most information in separate tables on the BLS's website, but maybe a more comprehensive dataset is available?

Comment: Have you tried to contact with them? Maybe they can provide data to you. Unfortunately, I didn't find any dataset with these information.

Comment: Which data and fields are you looking for?

Answer (score 3):

http://www.bls.gov/data/#api

You should be able to use the API to get the raw data.

Douglas

Comment: Actually, there is no series ID for the OOH data. So, no, the API is not going to work. Unless you can provide a more comprehensive answer and include the series ID. http://www.bls.gov/help/hlpforma.htm

Comment: @MeganSquire : it looks like the API's for time series only ... but there's 'Employment Projections' data at http://www.bls.gov/emp/#tables

Answer (score 2):

The BLS has a section for 'Employment Projections' at:

- http://www.bls.gov/emp/

They have links to :

- tables of data for download
- publications (including the one you mentioned)
- "databases" (web-based tables that you can search/order/etc.)